# Double NAT - connect to device via ssh

Tags: ssh, routes, vpn, lan

Quick question - my LAN at home:

```
INTERNET (public IP)
   v
ISP ROUTER (192.168.0.1, no access)
   v
PERSONAL ROUTER (192.168.1.1, full access)
   v
DEVICE (192.168.1.200)
```

Is it possible somehow to "expose" my device to the Internet, so I could remotely connect to it via ssh? Unfortunately I don't have an access to the ISP router, so can't setup port forwarding etc.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution would be to setup a VPN (i.e. openvpn) and connect to a VPN-server in the internet. Perhaps your `PERSONAL ROUTER` already has VPN-support in any way?

Drawback is, that you have to have an endpoint in the internet (a VPN-service or a (virtual) server).

Answer (score 0):

Set up a reverse SSH tunnel from your home server to the machine you want to connect from, or at least to a machine outside your double NAT environment, such as a VPS.

On your home server, set up the tunnel like this:

```
ssh -fNTR $REMOTE_USER@$REMOTE_IP:localhost:22 $REMOTE_PORT
```

What do those flags do?

- `-f` run in background
- `-N` don't execute a command, we're just forwarding traffic
- `-T` disable pseudo-terminal allocation to save resources
- `-R` On the remote side, forward SSH connections from $REMOTE_PORT to your home server.

On your remote server, connect back to the home server on the tunnel you set up like this:

```
ssh $HOME_USER@localhost -p $REMOTE_PORT
```

Please share this with the other eleventy gajillion people on the internet who asked this and weren't answered.